# Normalizing a signal to a particular value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, signal-processing, normalization

I have a signal in *MATLAB*, say

```
a= randn(1,1e4) + irandn(1,1e4);
```

I normalize it to power 1 by simply multiplying it by `sqrt(0.5),i.e a= sqrt(0.5)*(randn(1,1e4) + irandn(1,1e4));`

I want to normalize it to say power `3.9811e-06`. Does anyone have any idea of how to do it? I would highly appreciate suggestions.

Comment: you can normalize the power of your signal by dividing by the standard deviation of that signal, so I think you can normalize it to any power just by dividing? In your case divide by 1/3.9811e-6 ?

Comment: I want my signal a to have power 3.9811e-06. I dont think dividing 1 by this number would achieve my goal!

Answer (score 0):

If you normalize your signal by K, your signal power becomes 2K^2.

so if you want power to be equal to 1, =sqrt(0.5). similarly, if you want to have power = 3.9811e-6 then K=1.41086852e-3.